# Why can't I figure out the width of elements with automatic widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a sideways slideshow of images. The panel that will contain the slideshow is exactly 1200px wide. At page load, PHP loads images inside this panel. The number of images is not always the same, and I don't want the slideshow to start unless the collective width of the loaded images exceeds the width of the 1200px container.

The problem is, all the images are of various sizes, everything from 150x100 to 1980x1200. The images are fit into the bar by setting their height to 50 and letting their width rescale automatically.

Now, creating this slideshow panel in any other programming language would be easy. I'm suffering here in javascript though, because I simply can't find ANY WAY of getting the new width of the images. They all read width: 0px using jQuery outerWidth()

I have even tried putting a div wrapper inside the 1200px panel, outside the images, hoping that div would automatically scale around the width of the images and give me their collective width, but instead it reads 1200px (jQuery outerWidth())

Is there any way of measuring their width?
Is there an easier way of doing this?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You may want to post code. When are you checking image width?  The browser can't tell you what the width is until the image has been loaded ...

Comment: Don't do that; it's a big waste of bandwidth.  Use a server-side thumbnailer.

Comment: are you floating that DIV? a DIV with default browser CSS would expand to its parent's width, right guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to get the widths when the `document` is ready, instead of after the images have loaded.

Try placing the code that gets the `outerWidth()` in `$(window).load()`.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //get the image widths
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with getting the widths when document is ready? also isn't it a bad practice to shrink the images (to appear like thumbnails, i suppose) while the whole image is loaded (performance-wise)?

Comment: The "ready" condition for the document happens (potentially) before all the images have been retrieved from the server.

Comment: You are of course completely right. I used the document ready event (stupid me)